# 404 error when i add a new page

Tags: php, symfony

I have actually a problem when I want to get a new page in my website. When I am in localhost I have no problem with the page but when I want to get the new page in my prod server, I have a 404 error and I don't understand why :(

I use Symfony2 and my app/config/routing.yml is:

```
admin:
    resource: '@SonataAdminBundle/Resources/config/routing/sonata_admin.xml'
    prefix: /admin

_sonata_admin:
    resource: .
    type: sonata_admin
    prefix: /admin

logout:
    pattern:   /logout

#..................

kayser_platform:
    resource: "@KayserPlatformBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /

_liip_imagine:
    resource: "@LiipImagineBundle/Resources/config/routing.xml"
```

and my myBundle/ressources/views/config/routing.yml is:

```
# faq 
kay_faq:
    path:    /faq
    defaults: { _controller: KayserPlatformBundle:Default:faq}

#sonata admin
admin:
    resource: '@SonataAdminBundle/Resources/config/routing/sonata_admin.xml'
    prefix: /admin

_sonata_admin:
    resource: .
    type: sonata_admin
    prefix: /admin

login:
    pattern:   /login
    defaults:  { _controller: KayserPlatformBundle:Default:login }

login_check:
    pattern:   /login_check

kay_test:
    path:    /test
    defaults: { _controller: KayserPlatformBundle:Default:test}
```

For example, the path */test* doesn't work in prod but */fag* works well. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Did you remove the cache on prod: `php app/console cache:clear --env=prod` ?

Comment: No, i didn't. I will try

Comment: I use actually filezilla, do you have an idea how i can get a console with this ftp  ?

Comment: Ok i found the solution : i deleted my cache in : app/cache/prod and now all work well

Comment: I guess you will have the console only with an `VPS` hosting service, in other cases you should delete the folders as you did.

Answer (score 0):

After discussion in comments, the problem was located to be the `cache` for `prod` environment.

*Solution*: Clearing the cache solved the missing routes.

You can see your routes using the symfony2 command: `php app/console router:debug`